# The "Show all" button in my filterable module is not working on WordPress DIVI Theme

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, divi

I have a filterable module on my WordPress Divi-designed page. When running this code outside of WordPress upon refresh, the "Show All" button is active and shows all the products.

However, when I am trying to implement it in WordPress, upon refresh, the "Show All" button is active, but it doesn't show all the products unless I click on the button again.

```js
filterSelection("all")

function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bg img {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}

.filterDiv {
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
}


/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */

.show {
  display: block;
}


/* Style the buttons */

.btn {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0.8em 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  background-color: #151b54;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* Add a light grey background on mouse-over */

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #333972;
  transition: 1px;
}


/* Add a dark background to the active button */

.btn.active {
  background-color: #5B619A;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>Filter DIV Elements</h2>

<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('cars')"> Cars</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('animals')"> Animals</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('fruits')"> Fruits</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('colors')"> Colors</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="filterDiv cars">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
      <div class="bg">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1652489997196-90c654c0b584?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&raw_url=true&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1025" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2 style="color:white;font-size:180%"><b>Cars</b></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="filterDiv colors fruits">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
      <div class="bg">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1652489997196-90c654c0b584?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&raw_url=true&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1025" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2 style="color:white;font-size:180%"><b>Colors Fruits</b></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="filterDiv cars">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
      <div class="bg">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1652489997196-90c654c0b584?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&raw_url=true&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1025" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2 style="color:white;font-size:180%"><b>Cars</b></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="filterDiv colors">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
      <div class="bg">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1652489997196-90c654c0b584?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&raw_url=true&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1025" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2 style="color:white;font-size:180%"><b>Colors</b></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="filterDiv cars animals">
    <a href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
      <div class="bg">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1652489997196-90c654c0b584?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fm=jpg&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&raw_url=true&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1025" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2 style="color:white;font-size:180%"><b>Cars Animals</b></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your code does not use jQuery so I removed that tag and replaced it with Javascript

Comment: My bad, thanks. Can you suggest me a solution?

Comment: Not really, as the code in your question works fine in the fiddle. I'd suggest checking the console for errors when running your Wordpress site.

Comment: I have already gone through the console, and there isn't any error. While inspecting, upon refresh I can see "myBtnContainer<button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>" but still it doesn't show unless I click on the button again.